# React component not getting default state

Tags: reactjs, state

Trying to learn React/RoR and in this simple test app I have a 'searchapp' react app. That sets a default for the language radioboxes.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import axios from "axios";

import SearchForm from "./searchForm";

class SearchApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchStrings: [],
      subjectName: "",
      language: 'English',
      region: ""
    };
    this.getSearchStrings = this.getSearchStrings.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSearchStrings();
  }
  handleClickLang  = changeEvent => {
  this.setState({
    language: changeEvent.target.value
  });
};

  getSearchStrings() {
    axios
      .get("/api/v1/search_strings")
      .then(response => {
        const searchStrings = response.data;
        this.setState({searchStrings});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <>
    <SearchForm />
    </>
  );
  }
}
```

and then in the searchForm component I use that state to set and switch between two radio buttons.

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.subjRef = React.createRef();
    //this.handleClickLang = this.handleClickLang.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      language: 'English'
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert("sometext");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="my-3">
       <div className="form-row">
       <div className="form-group col-md-8">
       <p>Choose language</p>
       </div>
       <div className="form-row">
       <div className="form-check">
         <label>
           <input
             type="radio"
             name="react-tips"
             value="English"
             checked={this.state.language === 'English'}
             onChange={this.handleClickLang}
             className="form-check-input"
           />
           English
         </label>
       </div>
       <div className="form-check">
         <label>
           <input
             type="radio"
             name="react-tips"
             value="Russian"
             checked={this.state.language === 'Russian'}
             onChange={this.handleClickLang}
             className="form-check-input"
           />
           Russian
         </label>
       </div>
```

However when I run this I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'language')

I thought this was erroring because it cannot find a default language, however I initialised language to 'English' in the constructor for the SearchApp.

Is this me not understanding React state enough? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You don't appear to set `this.state` in the `SearchForm` constructor (or in the class body). I'm not sure what `this.setState` in `componentDidMount` does with that. Maybe check if instantiating `this.state` (even just to an empty object) helps, but I can't test it at the moment to confirm unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, adding
`this.state = {};` 
to my subcomponent removed this error, I guess I thought that the full state was automatically passed down from the app component, but it seems that is not the case. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the componentDidMount i feel the language is getting to null, you can try the following:

```js
Trying to learn React/RoR and in this simple test app I have a 'searchapp' react app. That sets a default for the language radioboxes.

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import axios from "axios";

import SearchForm from "./searchForm";

class SearchApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchStrings: [],
      subjectName: "",
      language: 'English',
      region: ""
    };
    this.getSearchStrings = this.getSearchStrings.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSearchStrings();
  }
  handleClickLang  = changeEvent => {
  this.setState({
    language: changeEvent.target.value
  });
};

  getSearchStrings() {
    axios
      .get("/api/v1/search_strings")
      .then(response => {
        const searchStrings = response.data;
        this.setState({searchStrings,language: 'English'});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <>
    <SearchForm language={this.state.language}/>
    </>
  );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And in the SearchForm component pass the language via props

```js
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.subjRef = React.createRef();
    //this.handleClickLang = this.handleClickLang.bind(this);
  }
 
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert("sometext");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="my-3">
       <div className="form-row">
       <div className="form-group col-md-8">
       <p>Choose language</p>
       </div>
       <div className="form-row">
       <div className="form-check">
         <label>
           <input
             type="radio"
             name="react-tips"
             value="English"
             checked={this.props.language === 'English'}
             onChange={this.handleClickLang}
             className="form-check-input"
           />
           English
         </label>
       </div>
       <div className="form-check">
         <label>
           <input
             type="radio"
             name="react-tips"
             value="Russian"
             checked={this.props.language === 'Russian'}
             onChange={this.handleClickLang}
             className="form-check-input"
           />
           Russian
         </label>
       </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

But there are several more things:

- Why are you also having language state in searchForm, you can have it in Search component and pass it via props
- Yo are not initializing any state in the constructor in your SearchForm component

Comment: Thank you Nacho, unfortunately this did not seem to solve the problem.
Adding state = {} to the component seems to have done the job.

Comment: Further to my above answer, the error stopping the compile was solved by initialising state in the subcomponent, but this answer from Nacho was correct in passing accessing the state of language in the App via props, passed down to the component. 
With this in mind I will accept this answer, but achkowledge that both Nacho and Thor84no are correct here. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a followup here for future reference.

As suggested by @Thor84no the problem was not adding `state = {}` to intialise state in the sub component.